# How to prevent React app from changing the functionality in production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, production-environment

I have created a chess app in react with typescript. The production build is compiled through react-scripts.

In my dev build, my app is correclty displaying the move notation.

E.g. e4, d5, exd5

[image: Gif of chess game]

However, in my production build, the moves are being displayed as:
Pe4, Pd5, Pxd5, etc.

I checked the production build code and the logic looked the same so I am unsure of why its breaking. I have tried changing the `piece.constructor.name === "Pawn"` comparison to `instanceof` and that did not work.

Here is a snippet of the dev code

```js
  const getMoveNotation = (piece: Piece, position: Position): string => {
    const captureMove = chessBoard.hasPiece(position);
    const coord = chessBoard.convertPositionToChessCoordinate(position);
    let moveNotation = "";
    if (piece.constructor.name != "Pawn") {
      moveNotation = `${piece.getPieceCode()}${coord}`;
      if (captureMove) {
        moveNotation = `${piece.getPieceCode()}x${coord}`;
      }
    } else {
      if (captureMove) {
        const pawnCoord = chessBoard
          .convertPositionToChessCoordinate(piece.getPosition())
          .charAt(0);
        moveNotation = `${pawnCoord}x${coord}`;
      } else {
        moveNotation = coord;
      }
    }

    return moveNotation;
  };
```

Here is the minified production version

```js
if("Pawn"!=e.constructor.name) a="".concat(e.getPieceCode()).concat(r),n&&(a="".concat(e.getPieceCode(),"x").concat(r));
else if(n){var i=s.convertPositionToChessCoordinate(e.getPosition()).charAt(0);a="".concat(i,"x").concat(r)}else a=r;
return a}
```

Comment: When you mention `dev build`, do you mean actually bundling it locally and serving the bundle in browser?

Comment: Compilers and bundlers sometimes changes the name of classes. So you shouldn't rely on `constructor.name`. `instanceof` should work though, what did you try with that and what about it did not work?

Comment: @codemax by dev build I meant hosting a dev server, not bundling

Comment: @AlexWayne thank you for the insight. I managed to get it working with changing the logic to instanceof everywhere. Thanks again

Comment: Similar issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50267543/class-name-always-e-for-every-class-after-uglify-webpack-for-production